How to implement client side connection failover in RSOCKET
I am running 2 instances of my RSOCKET Server app on localhost:7000 and localhost:5000, the expectation is that the client application should try connecting port 7000 and if the connection is good, then it will stay connected with 7000. In the middle of the run, if the connection is lost or the server is down, then the retry will kick off and after retrying for few times it should automatically attempt to connect the port 5000.
I could see a RequestBuilder.transports method that accepts LoadBalanceTargets. But this is only loadbalanced not used for failover. Can someone please help provide some samples to implement this?
